# Cpu usage 50% because of network activity

Tags: networking, cpu

Why is the cpu(celeron g1840) usage 50% and more (not reported as a system process) because of network activity to keeton.canonical.com, ftp.bit.nl and others?(os is loki)
I tracked it down up to:
32411 _apt     /usr/lib/apt/methods/http enp2s0     0.572  20.516 KB/sec
31916 _apt     /usr/lib/apt/methods/http enp2s0     0.547  20.490 KB/sec

It´s probably some update stuff, but the problem is it never seems to stop and using way too much cpu power, temp goes up as well.
I would have to change os if the bug can not be fixed, a dissapointment.

Answer (score 0):

I think its still a bug that needs to be picked up by the developers of elementary os. A process thats causing lots of cpu load and heat to the system is a serious bug.
The solution for my system seems to be:

1. Kill AppCenter

`killall appcenter`

2.Show all the hidden startup applications

sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop

3.launch Gnome Session Properties application

gnome-session-properties

4.Find AppCenter and uncheck it

Now it should update only when you'll click updates in AppCenter or via terminal with sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade Commands

Comment: It might be good to clarify that that `sed ...` command actually changes things and doesn't just "show" something. Novice users might not realize this and might not now how to reverse it.  
Maybe change to something like "Change startup config so started applications are shown at startup".
Maybe also include the  command to reverse this.